Why does Hibernate create multiple objects for the same entity?

If you get a child entity through a repo and through a parent entity, these will be two different objects
We will also get a different object if we want to save the child entity through the parent

In each case, we get more than one object for the same entity, which leads to a violation of data consistency. Why? Can this be fixed?
Examples:
@Entity
class Kid {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String parentId;
}

@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Kid> kids = new ArrayList<>();
}

//Ex1
var kid = kidRepo.findAll().get(0); //Kid@11111
var sameKid = parentRepo.findParent().getKids().get(0); //Kid@22222

assertTrue(kid.getId().equals(sameKid.getId()));
assertFalse(kid == sameKid);

//Ex2
var kid = new Kid(parent.getId()); //Kid@11111
var parent = parentRepo.findParent();
parent.getKids().add(kid);
parentRepo.save(parent);
var sameKid = parent.getKids.get(0); //Kid@22222

assertTrue(kid.getId().equals(sameKid.getId()));
assertFalse(kid == sameKid);

P.S: Thanks in advance

For Hibernate/JPA to determine if entities are the same you need to implement a proper equals and hashCode. Without those implemented Hibernate doesn't know which object is the same (as it will use those methods for it). Next to that if this isn't executed in the same transaction there is no way for hibernate to detect existing instances as the EntityManager is the cache, the EntityManager will be closed aft er the transaction has ended.

@M.Deinum If I save an object directly, this object will just be attached and all references to it will remain valid. When saving through the parent object, hibernate creates a new kid-object, and all references to the entity, except the parent, now become invalid. And it's not that equals returns false, but that there are now two objects per entity

Read, if you aren't in a single transaction it isn't attached. You aven't implemented equals so it will return false else it would return the same object, you are checking the id with equals. As stated hibernate needs a proper equals/hashcode implementntation to determine if something is the same or not.

You just need to override equals and hashCode for your asserts to work. You won't get the same exact instance from two different repos and/or queries lol. How would you expect Spring to know?

I expect the entities to be synchronized via the session cache. In addition, this does not explain why the kid-entity in the collection (parent.getKids().add(kid)) is replaced after parentRepo.save(parent)

This has nothing to do with Spring, it is how Hibernate (or rather JPA in general) works.

No way. It's impossible. That's the way Spring works

It looks like the session cache is not working properly

This has nothing to do with Spring, it is how Hibernate (or rather JPA in general) works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
